# How to remove Quotes from array result

Tags: javascript, html

```
[1: "["76.2350","21.9253"]", 3: "["10.5650","21.3653"]", 6: "["60.5650","55.3653"]"]
```

I have getting the result like this.
I want result like

```
[1: [76.2350,21.9253], 3: [10.5650,21.3653], 6: [60.5650,55.3653]]
```

here is my code

Comment: Can't you return the values as numbers from the backend?

Comment: Map and parseFloat

Comment: "Here is my code" ? edit the question with the code, you might have missclicked and not saved it.

Comment: Where do these values come from? It might be better to resolve this from wherever the data is stored. If your data source is a DB, it probably needs to store these values as numbers, not string. If you get this from an ORM, make sure it's configured to represent them as numbers.

Comment: you are entered invalid array `array` not have `key:value` pair i think this is object

Comment: If your result type is string you can use replace() method.

Comment: And why are you returning a string which is an array of strings  ???? (It's like having a picture of a book with pictures)

Comment: the data is getting from json file.

Comment: @DeepthiSNair .its a invalid .kindly  recheck your `JSON` result

Comment: please add a valid data structure.

Comment: var abc=[ ];

              for(_i = 0; _i < swipe_data.length; _i++){
                var tmp = swipe_data[_i];
                 var t1 = [swipe_data[_i]['latitude'], swipe_data[_i]['longitude']];
                 abc[tmp.id] = JSON.stringify(t1);

              }    I have getting result of "abc" like that..could u pls specify my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

try to put this data on string (str) the use replace method

```
 str = str.replace('"', '');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through your array and use replace:

```
str = str.replace(/"/g, "");  // RegEx to match `"` characters, with `g` for globally (instead of once)
```